# Problems with RCTImage in React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm getting two errors when trying to run my IOS project.
First one is located on a simulator screen and it's saying : 
**Invariant Violation: Native component for “RCTImageView” does not exist**

This is my error inside console: **ExceptionsManager.js:65 Invariant Violation: View config not found for name RCTImageView**

Problem is that my RCTImage is located inside Podfile, but
I can not find RCTImageView in my node-modules so I can move it to Xcode and manually link that lib.

Does anyone have some kind of solution for this?

It says that it's located inside component below:

```
/**
 * A single button as displayed on the main menu
 */
export default class ClockComponent extends Component {
    handlePress() {
        this.props.onPress();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationTouch
                onPress={() => this.handlePress()}
                style={Style.mainMenuElementContainer}
            >
                <View style={[Style.mainMenuElement, this.props.colorStyle]}>
                    <Image source={this.props.icon} style={Style.mainMenuElementIcon} resizeMode="contain" />
                    <Text
                        style={Style.text}
                        minimumFontScale={0.9}
                        numberOfLines={3}
                    >
                        {this.props.title}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </NavigationTouch>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RCTImage` will be available inside `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image`.

Copy `RCTImage.xcodeproj` to your `Libraries` folder and link it.

Comment: i found RCTImage.xcodeproj folder in that node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image folder. Where should i copy that, xcode left-hand side Libraries already has that file, how can i be sure that i linked? Is running "react-native link" is enough? thanks

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios very helpful link